# Why does my Javascript setTimeout function behaves like a setInterval?

Tags: javascript, timer, clock

As part of an exercise, I wrote a simple function to show a "binary clock", a clock that "ticks" each two seconds, instead of one. The function I wrote is actually a modification of a similar code that does it in an HTML form (a value in the form is changed time and again).

Here's my JS-only modification:

```
function binaryClock() {                        
    let currentTime = new Date();
    let hr = currentTime.getHours();
    let mn = currentTime.getMinutes();
    let sc = currentTime.getSeconds();

    setTimeout('binaryClock()', 2000);
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    document.write(hr + ':' + mn + ':' + sc + ' '); 
}

binaryClock();
```

Why does it actually works intervallic, as any clock would in the sense that `setTimeout` acts like setInterval on the binaryClock callback?

I mean, if I use `setInterval()` instead, I get the exact same result, and as a beginner, I still don't have enough knowledge to explain why in this particular case, `setTimeout()` (which usually runs once) will work like `setInterval()` in this case and saw it enough important to ask it here as I never came across such a difference in my studies.

Comment: Every time you call `binaryClock` a `Timeout` is being `set` which calls `binaryClock`; …which `set`s a `Timeout` which calls `binaryClock`; …which `set`s a `Timeout` which calls `binaryClock`; …which `set`s a `Timeout` which calls `binaryClock`; …which `set`s a `Timeout` which calls `binaryClock`…

Comment: I understand the recurisivness now and will call this behavior recursive when I see a function containing a call to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to deceze who commented, I understand I missed the implementation of recursivness in the original code. I now understand the function calls itself each time it runs, via the call inside setTimeout() or setInterval:

It is called in each tick, while only the 2 seconds are taken into effect, as the function would could itself recursively either way due to way the language is commonly interpreted.

Thus, a setInterval() like behavior would be achieved from the recursivness either way.

Comment: I did the exact same thing and was searching for the same. Found out by myself just before I stumbled on this answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Why does my Javascript setTimeout function behaves like a setInterval?"

Because you've made it that way.  You are calling your function `binaryClock()` recursively.

Answer (score 1):

It works like setInterval since you are doing a setTimeout(binaryClick,2000) on each tick.

so basically, each time your clock "ticks" it starts the next tick